# Rails has_many and belongs_to association methods with unexpected behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-many, belongs-to

I recently stumbled upon a strange behaviour with some of the methods added by `belongs_to` and `has_many`.

Consider the following scenario, as presented by [Rail's Active Record Association guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books, inverse_of: :author
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, inverse_of: :books
end
```

If I use `belongs_to`'s `association=(associate)` [method](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference), I loose reference to book from author:

```
book = Book.new
author = Author.new
book.author = author
author.books.include?(book) # false, expected true
author.books.empty? # true, expected to contain book
```

But if I make the association with `has_many`'s `collection<<(object)` [method](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference), the reference persists as expected:

```
book = Book.new
author = Author.new
author.books << book
author.books.include?(book) # true, as expected
author.books.empty? # false, as expected
book.author == author # true, as expected
```

Is this the expected behaviour? I don't quite understand why the first case does not store the association from `author` to `book`.

I'm using ruby 2.5.1 and rails 5.2.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Inspect `book` and `author`. Because you do `new`, and not `create`, neither have an `id`. So, the association can't be set correctly with `book.author = author` (there is no `author.id` to set as `author_id` on `book`).

Comment: @jvillian I understand that, but I expected the association to be stored in memory, just as (I think) it does when using `collection<<(object)` instead of `association=(associate)`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'stored in memory' when there is no foreign key to be set on `book.author_id`. You could, however, take a look at the source code and I'm sure all would be made clear. BTW, I suspect that if you look in your console you might also find some illuminating information.

Answer (score 0):

`author.books << book` builds an `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`. So with `author.books.include? book` you are checking if it exists inside that collection (not yet stored in db): it's true.

With just `book.save` you can save both `book` and `author`.

Conversely, `book.author = author` is just an assignment. You need to `author.save` and `book.save` to effectively build the relation. If you check author.books.include?(book) after the two save, if becomes true.

Try it in rails console.